# Get all days in a month excluding weekends postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I want to write a query sql for postgresql that can basically return me all days of a month excluding weekends.

For example (For 11/2019) :

- First Week: 11/1
- Second Week : 11/4 -> 11/8
- Third Week : 11/11 -> 11/15
- Fouth Week : 11/18 -> 11/22
- Fifth Week : 11/25 -> 11/29

I can't find any postgresql request that can help, this should be automatic instead of putting each time a new date manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is:

```
select dt 
from generate_series(date'2019-11-01', date'2019-11-30', interval '1' day) as t(dt)
where extract(dow from dt) between 1 and 5
```

`generate_series()` produces a list of all days in the month, then the `where` clause filters on week days only.